# Qual o problema? Uso o PyCharm

Tags: python

```
def par_ou_impar(result):
    divided = str(result).split('.')
    if len(divided) < 2:
        if divided[0] % 2 == 0:
            print('O resultado é par')
        else:
            print('O resultado é ímpar')
    if int(divided[1]) % 2 == 0:
        print('O resultado é par')
    else:
        print('O resultado é ímpar')


is_float = True

try:
    numero1 = float(input('Digite o primeiro número:'))
except Exception:
    is_float = False

while not is_float:
    print('Favor digitar um número válido')
    try:
        numero1 = float(input('Digite o primeiro número:'))
        is_float = True
    except Exception:
        is_float = False

is_float = True

try:
    numero2 = float(input('Digite o segundo número:'))
except Exception:
    is_float = False

while not is_float:
    print('Favor digitar um número válido')
    try:
        numero2 = float(input('Digite o segundo número:'))
        is_float = True
    except Exception:
        is_float = False

print('Info.: Número1 () Número2')
print('1 para soma')
print('2 para subtração')
print('3 para multiplicação')
print('4 para divisão')

is_int = True

try:
    operacao = int(input('Digite a operação que você quer realizar:'))
    if 5 > operacao > 0:
        is_int = True
    else:
        is_float = False
except Exception:
    is_int = False

while not is_int:
    print('Favor digitar um valor válido inteiro')
    try:
        operacao = int(input('Digite a operação que você quer realizar:'))
        if 5 > operacao > 0:
            is_float = True
        else:
            is_float = False
    except Exception:
        is_int = False

if operacao == 1:
    result = numero1 + numero2
elif operacao == 2:
    result = numero1 - numero2
elif operacao == 3:
    result = numero1 * numero2
elif operacao == 4:
    result = numero1 / numero2

if result % int(result) == 0:
    print('O resultado é:', int(result))
else:
    print('O resultado é:', result)

if result >= 0:
    print('O resultado é positivo')
else:
    print('O resultado é negativo')

if round(result) == result:
    print('O resultado é inteiro')
else:
    print('O resultado é decimal')

par_ou_impar(result)
```

Está dando este erro:

```
Digite o primeiro número:2
Digite o segundo número:3
Info.: Número1 () Número2
1 para soma
2 para subtração
3 para multiplicação
4 para divisão
Digite a operação que você quer realizar:6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/AppsTo/PycharmProjects/EstruturaDeDecisão/Exec24.py", line 81, in <module>
    if result % int(result) == 0:
NameError: name 'result' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Mas não deveria chegar ao result se o `operacao` não está dando certo.

Comment: Você digitou a operação 6, ele não vai entrar em nenhum `if` ou `elif` que inicializam a variável `result`, qnd tenta acessar a variável que não foi inicializada dá erro.

Comment: Sim, mas é pra isso que isso serve...

try:
    operacao = int(input('Digite a operação que você quer realizar:'))
    if 5 > operacao > 0:
        is_int = True
    else:
        is_float = False

Comment: Nesse caso então vc errou o nome da variável dentro do `else` do primeiro `try catch` e também no `if` e `else` no segundo `try catch`, deveria ser `is_int` e não `is_float`

Comment: Isso, é isso mesmo.. Agora só preciso testar se ele pegou o float

Comment: Ainda sim deu erro, na hora de fazer o float.. Veja bem.

Digite o primeiro número:3
Digite o segundo número:5
Info.: Número1 () Número2
1 para soma
2 para subtração
3 para multiplicação
4 para divisão
Digite a operação que você quer realizar:4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/AppsTo/PycharmProjects/EstruturaDeDecisão/Exec24.py", line 81, in <module>
    if result % int(result) == 0:
ZeroDivisionError: float modulo

Mas creio que está correto, não está?

Comment: if result % int(result) == 0:
    print('O resultado é:', int(result))
else:
    result = float(round(result, 4))
    print('O resultado é:',  float(result))

Arrumei assim e está dando problemas Vejam:

Digite o primeiro número:2
Digite o segundo número:8
Info.: Número1 () Número2
1 para soma
2 para subtração
3 para multiplicação
4 para divisão
Digite a operação que você quer realizar:4
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/AppsTo/PycharmProjects/EstruturaDeDecisão/Exec24.py", line 81, in <module>
    if result % int(result) == 0:
ZeroDivisionError: float modulo

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei se isso vai afetar outras partes mas tenta fazer assim.

```
is_int = True

try:
    operacao = int(input('Digite a operação que você quer realizar:'))
    if 5 > operacao > 0:
        is_int = True
    else:
        is_int = False
except Exception:
    is_int = False

while not is_int:
    print('Favor digitar um valor válido inteiro')
    try:
        operacao = int(input('Digite a operação que você quer realizar:'))
        if 5 > operacao > 0:
            is_int = True
        else:
            is_int = False

    except Exception:
        is_int = False
```

Comment: Não enteido o que você quis dizer amigo... o erro está no fim.

Comment: Porque no original, retorna o erro de que result não está difinido, mas mesmo explicitando ele antes vai dar erro de ZerodivizionError. A única saída foi faze isso ali.

Comment: Posso estar errado, mas vocÊ copiou o que eu ja fiz..

Comment: Mas isso eu já arrumei, acho que já até falei isso... O problema ta sendo onde eu disse no fim.

if result % int(result) == 0: print('O resultado é:', int(result)) else: result = float(round(result, 4)) print('O resultado é:', float(result)) Arrumei assim e está dando problemas Vejam: Digite o primeiro número:2 Digite o segundo número:8 Info.: Número1 () Número2 1 para soma 2 para subtração 3 para multiplicação 4 para divisão Digite a operação que você quer realizar:4 Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/AppsTo/PycharmProjects/EstruturaDeDecisão/Exec24.py", line 81, in <module> if

Comment: @IgorMunhoz entendo, acho que me confundi então.

Comment: Eu ainda acho que o erro está no result não explicitado antes da Estrutura de decisão, no seu lugar eu tentaria usar o lambda, ficaria mais fácil.